# How uninstall/delete MSDN Library - January 2002 from my machine?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation

I am cleaning up my machine and found cannot uninstall `MSDN Library - January 2002` due to an error. It takes 1.3G disk space. I want to remove it. any idea where it is and how to manually remove it? or any free tool can do the trick for me? I am plan to install Visual Studio 2008 professional. I am using Windows XP.
thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Comment: I think the OP has already tried this. Because it is so much data, if you just want to free space you could simply find the data and remove the directory. Then you will probably end up with a bunch of dead links etc., but you will inevitably free 1.3 GB of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml) and look for the 1.3gb directory.